# Docker Dev Environnement with Rust

Tags: docker, rust, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a development environment with Docker from a guithub repository.
I would like to use the "docker/dev-environments-default" image as a base and add the Rust tool chain to it. I tried adding a compose-dev.yaml file with the following script:

```
services:
  app:
    entrypoint:
    - sleep
    - infinity
    image: docker/dev-environments-default
    init: true
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: /var/run/docker.sock
      target: /var/run/docker.sock
  rust:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: rust_lib
```

I also added a Dockerfile inside the rust_lib folder with the following script:

```
FROM rust AS build
WORKDIR /rust/src/github.com/org/repo
COPY . .
```

The development container starts fine but it does not contain the Rust tool chain.

When I try to start the Rust container by hand it immediately stops with exit code 0.

Any idea on how to set up a development environment with Rust tools?

Comment: I'm actually looking to build a Rust dev environment isolated from my local system with a vscode server inside.

Comment: I created a container based on the "docker/dev-environments-default" image and installed Rust inside it. I was expecting the container to be reset on reboot but that's not the case. The packages I installed are still there. I thought only data mapped into volumes was persistent but maybe that's specific to dev environments.

Comment: No clarity on objective of the task and what is the question here? What you expected in the answer?

Answer (score -1):

Actually Docker automatically inject the development environment into a chosen image.
I created a .docker directory with a Dockerfile.dev file containing:

```
FROM rust:latest
WORKDIR /srv/repo/src/
COPY . .
```

And a config.json containing the following code:

```
{
    "Dockerfile": "Dockerfile.dev"
}
```

Comment: A compose-dev.yaml is sufficient : services:
  app:
    image: rust:latest
    entrypoint:
    - sleep
    - infinity
    init: true
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: /var/run/docker.sock
      target: /var/run/docker.sock

Comment: See https://docs.docker.com/desktop/dev-environments/set-up/ for the config.json

Comment: The line inside config.json forces docker to use a particular Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml to build the development environment.

Comment: Ok, it seems like I have no experience with this particular type of docker infrastructure. In that case probably ignore all of my comments.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).